# How to make a CMake custom command depends on a target being built but without rerunning on relink?

Tags: cmake, build

I have a executable used to generate a "cache" file. In CMake, I have something like this:

```
add_executable(Generator ...)
add_custom_target(OUTPUT cache
    DEPENDS Generator OtherDep1 OtherDep2
    COMMAND Generator --input OtherDep1 OtherDep2 --output cache)
```

However, because it takes about 10 minutes and I do not care of the `cache` differs when `Generator` changes, I do not want `cache` to be re-computed whenever `Generator` is re-linked for whatever reason. But if I remove `Generator` from the dependencies, it may not be available when the custom commands needs it.

I know this is a bit far from the usual Make/CMake workflow, but is there something I can do to require `Generator` to have been compiled before running the custom command?

Comment: so in pseudocode just `COMMAND if output not exists ; then ./generator ; fi`?

Comment: wouldn't that be opting out of a correctness feature? What if the re-link is for changes in behaviour that change what Generator generates?

Comment: @starball Yes it would, but as I said, due to the nature of the cache, I don't care. If that change I can always add back the dependency on Generator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I do not want `cache` to be re-computed whenever `Generator` is re-linked for whatever reason.

Then you need to define **target**-level dependencies instead of **file**-level ones. Target-level dependencies are defined with `add_dependencies` command:

```cmake
add_executable(Generator ...)

# Custom command for **file-level** dependencies.
# The output will be rebuilt whenever it will be found older than one of its dependencies.
add_custom_command(OUTPUT cache
    DEPENDS OtherDep1 OtherDep2
    COMMAND Generator --input OtherDep1 OtherDep2 --output cache)

# Custom target.
# It just makes sure, that its dependencies are up-to-date.
add_custom_target(create_cache
   DEPENDS cache
)

# **target-level** dependencies between the targets.
# They ensures only order, but do not cause rebuilding of one target
# because of another target has been rebuilt
add_dependencies(create_cache Generator)
```